# AS3 - How to fire an event precisely in time (framerate independent) like: every 1 or 5 milliseconds

Tags: actionscript-3, timer

I wonder if it's possible to fire an event independently of flash framerate. Tried timer class, setTimeout - setInterval and so.. but these strongly depends on frames.

For example this:

```
var a = 0;
var timer:Timer = new Timer(5);
timer.start();

timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, valAdd)

function valAdd(e:TimerEvent)
{
    a++;
}
```

acts similar to Event.ENTER_FRAME..
as I checked variable "a" after a second I got around 118-120 running at 60fps, not 200 as expected (timer every 5ms) So I'm looking for a solution for this. Thank you in advance for any advices regarding my little issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Timer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html) manual:

> Depending on the SWF file's framerate or the runtime environment (available memory and other factors), the runtime may dispatch events at slightly offset intervals. For example, if a SWF file is set to play at 10 frames per second (fps), which is 100 millisecond intervals, but your timer is set to fire an event at 80 milliseconds, the event will be dispatched close to the 100 millisecond interval. Memory-intensive scripts may also offset the events.

This means you can never create a timer which will work on such small precision, e.g. 5 millisecond. 5 millisecond is a very small time and the run time system itself does lots of works under the hood. These timers are never that much precise.

You need to re-design your solution which does not require a timer of such small interval.

This timer precision problem is not present only in AS3 or flash. Timers of other languages, run times (e.g. NSTimer of iOS) also don't work with such small interval.

Comment: That is a little.. disappointing.. but you are probably right. I wondered if I can do something like this in different manner, not using timers, setIntervals and so. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: The Flash runtime doesn't keep accurate time. If you're doing something that requires that kind of responsiveness, you need to look into more native solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Try using setInterval:

```
function myHello (){
    trace("Hello");
}

setInterval(myHello, 5);
```

Note that 5 ms is a very small amount of time... your PC also executes other software!

Comment: yes, i did suspect that, probably Timer relies on setInterval... see my footer edit

Answer (score 0):

I want to post another answer. You could use JavasScript to time your event more precisely. It also uses setInterval / setTimeout and then just call a method in the swf to do your stuff. js way simpler and perhaps you could get some sort of precision. Pretty simple to do it. Check out ExternalInterface of flash.

Comment: Seemed like pretty cool idea, so I tried it. Maximum precision it can achieve is near.. 120fps, but no more. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

What if you set the frame rate to something ridiculously high like 200 or even 1000 FPS, but only executed the expensive tasks, like redrawing the screen, at an ordinary frame rate (qualifying that code with something like the following)?

```
if (aCounter % 40 == 0) {
//do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I'm late (**FLASH is dead**) but You forgot the method `updateAfterEvent();`

Even with an updateAfterEvent and a **framerate of 1** this **interval is too short**

So remember that Your interval is independent of Your framerate (good to know)!!!

```
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.text.TextField;
import flash.text.TextFormat;

var t:Timer = new Timer(5);
var tfield:TextField = new TextField();
var tformat:TextFormat = new TextFormat("Verdana",26,0,true);
var a = 0;
addChild(tfield);
t.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER,display);

function display(e:TimerEvent):void{
    a++
    tfield.text =("a = " + a);
    tfield.setTextFormat(tformat);
    e.updateAfterEvent();
}
t.start();
```